# Annotation Validation

Tags: json, spring, validation, annotations

Ok, first I can valid the user if I am using `@Valid` and the incoming is `User` instance instead of json string. That works fine e.g:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
    userRep.save(user);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

So the question is how can I create some kind of API and the incoming is Json string, and validate the annotation automatically, for example, `@Email`, `@NotEmpty`? What is the best practice?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> createFromJson(@RequestBody String json) {    
  User user = User.fromJsonToUser(json);
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(user.toJson(),header,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

User.class

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 30)
    private String firstName;

    @Email        
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min = 3 , max = 50)
    private String primaryEmail;

}
```

Comment: You can annotate a `@RequestBody` annotated parameter with `@Valid` as well.

Comment: `@Valid` the json string? (`@RequestBody` `@Valid` String json) but I want the validate the User object

Answer (score 0):

Simply let Spring parse the String to a User and annotate it with the same @Valid annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> createFromJson(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {    
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(user.toJson(), header, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

or even

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<User> createFromJson(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {    
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, header, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: but how? spring won't just parse the json string to User object, what do i need to do in order to make it work?

Comment: I am not sure what am i missing. i got the error - The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ()

Comment: You must have the Jackson JSON mapper in the classpath. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-json-mapping and grep "Jackson" in this documentation.

Comment: is there any example? all I find is returning Json instead of receiving? and it seems i am missing something simple but i couldn't google it! any working example with configuration would be appreciated